# Node Express Server connection times out when server processes a request more than 120seconds

Tags: node.js, express

I am stuck with request timeout error whenever sending a request to NodeJS express server that takes more than 120seconds for responding to client.

I tried with increasing the server timeout with `request.setTimeOut(200000);`, but it works only when accessed from localhost.. and times out thorough the IP address. And same problem when runs in a website too.

Please find my server code to hold the request for more than 120 seconds:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3003);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
app.post('/cmfm', function (req, res) {
    req.setTimeout(600000);
    //req.socket.setKeepAlive(true,1);    
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    var response = {};
    response.data = 1;
    console.log('request starts to process.. ');
    setTimeout(function () {
        var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log('Total Time taken to run --> ' + (endTime - startTime));
        res.json(response);
    }, 180000);
});
```

Client side Code to request the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/cmfm",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json", // content type is must    
    cache: false,
}).done(function (resultdata) {
    alert('timout passed - ' + resultdata.data);
})
.fail(function () {
    alert('Timout failed');
});
```

From

- localhost:3003
  It works as expected. ajax done is triggered after 180seconds
- IPADDRESS:3003
  It triggers ajax.fail() after 120seconds exactly without finishing the setTimeOut Callback fn in server.

Please help me to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can try to set the timeout client side

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/cmfm",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  timeout: 200000,
  cache: false,
}).done(function (resultdata){
  alert('timout passed - ' + resultdata.data);
}).fail(function() {
  alert('Timout failed');
});
```

Otherwise seems like the connection timeout is triggered by something between the client and the server (ex. proxy, firewall, ecc...)

Comment: Thanks..ajax timeout doesnt help me ... but Solved now.. Solution - just unplugged from my office netwrok and connected by external network using data card. So i Guess it must be firewall/proxy issue... Further i narrow down and post the exact change to be done on the network side.